# LCD screen cover that can cling

Tags: display, lcd

Is there a material that will cling to an LCD screen and be perfectly opaque?

Basically I want to apply it to the monitor and have it cling to the monitor and block it completely so no light comes out.

I tried mylar and that did not work.

Comment: "block it completely so no light comes out." What do you exactly mean by that? Are you talking about the light that would illuminate the room, if it were dark?

Comment: why didnt the mylar work? a black sign vinyl might work, the materials used to make signs and to temporarily (using the sticky clingy nature of vinyl) stick a sign or wrap on a car.  You should probably analise how that would change the cooling properties of the monitor. EX: putting hard running leds face down or in containment , the light itself not departing the leds, and the heat not leaving as easily will cook them into a short life.   Such a tiny change but it could be conciderable if cooling is barely spec already.  We dont feel a lot of heat pouring off, but they are not 100% efficient.

Comment: You could just throw a blanket over it. ;-)  If you tell us a little more about what you are trying to accomplish, rather than direct us to a solution, we can help you.

Comment: @DrZoo I want a film that will cling to an LCD screen (like a laptop display) and be opaque.

Comment: @Psycogeek The mylar did not cling to the screen.